# How to unbind a key?

Tags: key-bindings

I want to get rid of the `C-e` binding so I can bind `C-e e`, and `C-e r` to a command. How do I do this?

My init file has this:

```lisp
    (global-set-key (kbd "C-e e") 'move-end-of-line)
    (global-set-key (kbd "C-e r") 'end-of-buffer)
```

Comment: Here is what I do for `C-d` -- perhaps it would work for you using `C-e` instead? -- the *help-for-help* function is just an arbitrary example:  `(defalias 'ctl-d-keymap (make-sparse-keymap)) (defvar ctl-d-map (symbol-function 'ctl-d-keymap) "Global keymap for characters following C-d.") (define-key global-map "\C-d" 'ctl-d-keymap) (define-key ctl-d-map "z" 'help-for-help)`

Comment: Sadly didn't work :( but thanks anyway!

Comment: What do you get when you do `C-h k C-e`?

Comment: If you have a major-mode or a minor-mode that is active and uses `C-e`, then those key bindings will trump a global setting -- minor trumps major, and major trumps global.  So, you would need to do what *kaushalmodi* is suggesting to track down which of those circumstances is likely at issue.  Once you figure that out, then you can unset those keys.  Here is an example for unsetting org-mode key bindings (a major mode):  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17540326/2112489

Comment: If, for example, you have a stock Emacs installation (built for OSX) with zero user configuration, the answer to *kaushalmodi*'s question is:  **"C-e runs the command move-end-of-line (found in global-map), which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in 'simple.el'.  It is bound to C-e.  (move-end-of-line ARG)"** Absent you providing an answer to that specific question, everyone here is just going to be guessing what the conflict might be.  And, of course, it is always a good idea to restart Emacs when adding/modifying settings so that those new settings can take effect.

Comment: Cross-referencing with https://stackoverflow.com/a/13966287/324105

Answer (score 32):

You can [unset the key](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Commands.html) in at least two ways:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-e") nil)
(global-unset-key (kbd "C-e"))
```

Note that I got this information with a web search for [emacs unset key](https://www.google.com/search?q=emacs+unset+key&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb).

Comment: Neither worked :(

Comment: @JoshuaLilleberg: you're going to have to provide more information before we can help.

Comment: What do you mean more info? Do you want to know what I'm running? What I put in my .emacs? I dont understand...

Comment: Thanks. This also worked for combinations like `(global-unset-key (kbd "C-h h"))`.

Comment: The second one, `global-unset-key` worked for me.

Comment: This does not revert to older binding. When a new binding is made the information about the older binding is lost .

Comment: Relevant links: [GNU Rebinding](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Rebinding.html), [GNU Commands for Binding Keys](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Commands.html)

Answer (score 7):

See @lawlist's comment.

Use `C-h m`, `C-h k`, and `C-h b` wherever you want to make the change.  That will help you figure out the keymap in which you need to make the change. If Dan's suggestion didn't help then clearly that keymap is not the global map.

Setting the key binding to `nil` is indeed the way to unbind it.  You just need to do that in the right map.

Using `C-h M-k` (`describe-keymap`), from library [`help-fns+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/help-fns%2b.el) will give you a human-readable list of the bindings in a given keymap (bound to a keymap variable, such as `global-map`.

Comment: I looked through the C-h b place, I found C-e , it was in the Global Bindings category, I don't know what to do know.

Comment: What does `C-h k` tell you in the buffer in question? If it says something like `C-e runs the command move-end-of-line (found in global-map)` then the binding is from the global map, and `(global-set-key (kbd "C-e") nil)` should be sufficient. If it is not then you will need to show us more context. And be sure to start from `emacs -Q` (no init file) - we won't try to guess whatever might be in your init file and setup.

Comment: All it says is:
C-e runs the command move-end-of-line, which is an interactive
compiled Lisp function.

It is bound to C-e, <end>.

(move-end-of-line ARG)

Move point to end of current line as displayed.
With argument ARG not nil or 1, move forward ARG - 1 lines first.
If point reaches the beginning or end of buffer, it stops there.

To ignore the effects of the `intangible' text or overlay
property, bind `inhibit-point-motion-hooks' to t.
If there is an image in the current line, this function
disregards newlines that are part of the text on which the image
rests.

Comment: So Emacs says that `C-e` is bound to `move-end-of-line`. And you try `M-x global-unset-key C-e` and try `C-h k C-e` and it still tells you that it is bound to `move-end-of-line`. Right? Try doing that same thing after starting Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file). No doubt it will work. If so, and if it doesn't work when you load your init file (just `emacs`, not `emacs -Q`), then something in your init file is causing the problem. Recursively bisect your init file to find what that something is. You can comment out 1/2, then 3/4, 7/8 etc. of your init file using command `comment-region`.

Comment: This answer would be complete with an example for unsetting in a different map

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to unset a key before you rebind it to something else. This should do what you want:

```
;; create a new prefix map
(define-prefix-command 'my-keymap)
;; bind the new keymap to C-e 
(global-set-key "\C-e" my-keymap)
;; bind the individual commands:
(define-key my-keymap "e" 'move-end-of-line)
(define-key my-keymap "r" 'end-of-buffer)
```

Now hitting `C-e` is a prefix, and `C-e e` calls `end-of-line` etc.