# How to "remove" a remapping so that I can access the underlying (remapped) command?

Tags: key-bindings

I use `projectile` and `helm-projectile`. Sometimes I like to use `helm-projectile-grep` to explore the code dynamically, and sometimes I know what I am looking for and I want the speed, and persistence of `projectile-grep`.

However, when I map `projectile-grep` to a key, when I use that key it seems to call `helm-projectile-grep`. This is my current config:

```
(use-package projectile
  :ensure t
  :demand t
  :config
  (projectile-mode +1)
  (define-key projectile-mode-map (kbd "s-p") 'projectile-command-map)
  (setq projectile-switch-project-action 'projectile-dired)
  (define-key projectile-command-map (kbd "g") 'projectile-grep))

(use-package helm-projectile
  :ensure t
  :demand t
  :after (projectile)
  :bind ("s-f" . helm-projectile-find-file)
  :config
  (helm-projectile-on))
```

How can I use separate key bindings for `helm-projectile-grep` and `projectile-grep`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to unbind a key?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12383/how-to-unbind-a-key)

Comment: I can't see how it does.

Comment: You ask *how you can remove a command remapping.* That's the same as asking how you unbind the `[remap ___]` pseudo key, i.e., how to unbind it. And the answer is to bind it to `nil`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `helm-projectile` is doing this:

```
(define-key projectile-mode-map [remap projectile-grep] #'helm-projectile-grep)
```

You would disable that with:

```
(define-key projectile-mode-map [remap projectile-grep] nil)
```

Comment: Should `projectile-command-map` be `projectile-mode-map` ? If so this seems to work for me.

Comment: Cool, I'll update the answer.  I was just basing that on the `(define-key projectile-command-map (kbd "g") 'projectile-grep))` code that you'd shown.