# How to disable multiple elpy keybindings?

Tags: elpy

There are multiple `elpy` keybindings that I am not using. Is there any way to unbind them?
Possible bindings that I want to disable `C-c C-t`, `C-c C-p`.

I have tried following answer [Globally override key binding in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/683575/2402577) but it did not help.

---

I have also tried following, which did not work. Still does keybindings are bind to `elpy`.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-t") nil)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-p") nil)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to unbind a key?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12383/how-to-unbind-a-key)

Comment: I have also tried `(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-t") nil)` but it does not work. `elpy` keeps overwritten all keybindings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`describe-key` (<kbd>C-h k C-c C-t</kbd>) shows that <kbd>C-c C-t</kbd> is defined into the `elpy-mode-map`, so you have to unbind the key from this map:

```el
(define-key elpy-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-t") nil)
```

Comment: `C-c C-t` is still bind to `c → python-skeleton-class f → python-skeleton-for` etc. Is it possible to disable that too? I think that one comes from `python-mode`

Comment: These are defined in the `python-mode-map` so you can unbind them with `(define-key python-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-t") nil)`