# Disable mouse-3 (right click) from deleting/killing text

Tags: key-bindings, mouse

Is there an easy way to disable mouse-3 (right click) from killing selected regions? I didn't see anything in the customize options that looked like it would do it. Wouldn't mind disabling middle button click paste as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to unbind a key?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12383/how-to-unbind-a-key)

Comment: You're right, @Drew, I meant `kill`. The other does answer my question, but I do not know how long it would have taken me to realize that on my own; I wasn't thinking in terms of unbinding a key from an action so much as setting an option for whatever functionality is bound to mouse-3 by default.

Comment: Edited title per your comment: kill, not yank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `(global-set-key [mouse-3] nil)` should do it

Comment: Aka `(global-unset-key [mouse-3])`

Comment: That looks slightly more elegant indeed. I see that that function is described in [Changing Key Bindings Interactively](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Rebinding.html), but it is not described in [Rebinding Keys in Your Init File](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-Rebinding.html). Well, we keep learning...